# css difference between firefox/Mac & firefox/Windows

Tags: css, windows, macos, firefox

I'm working on a template with a designer and we see different things. In my browser on mac the input field are next to the labels but for the designer in his browser the input fields are under the labels.

I use eric meyer's css reset so everything should be correct. Here's a screenshot to illustrate what I mean (left is what it should be and on the right what it shouldn't be)

[image]

Does anyone know how this could be fixed?

Comment: Can you show us the code you're using?

Comment: initial guess: `text <input>` is wrapping due to container padding

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If field sizes are given in `em`s, then change them to `px`.

`em` is dependent on font-size, and font sizes aren't pixel-perfect (different browsers round it differently, exact width may depend on font, especially if that gap between fields is a space).

Leave some room in the container (just make containing element few pixels wider than it has to be).

You may also try:

```
input {
 box-sizing: border-box; 
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Which makes sizes of form elements a little bit more consistent.

Comment: Leaving some room is good but what should be done if we want to make inner elements touch the containing box edges? For example, in case of horizontal Main Menu of a site?

Comment: @D3K You could use `display:inline-block` for the items (avoid whitespace in the source!) and `white-space:nowrap` on the container. For floats with percentage or em sizes I don't know any way to guarantee pixel-perfect sum.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is asked a long time ago but I was having a similar problem today and thought I share the solution that worked for me.

Put a `font-size` and `width` on the input field, this might help as it seems the default values for `font-size` is (or can be) different in windows and mac. In this way you can continue to use `em`s, which I personally prefer to use.

Comment: input is always welcome :) thank you. I don't really like em because the parent can easily influence it. However it's new brother rem seems to solve that problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] if you are using php or check how to get the user agent in your chosen server side programming language. Based on the user agent, you can then stick the condition in the head section of the html document to print the css. Make sure it is the last in the order so that you can override your previously written css. This is just one option. This is useful if you have complex design.