# When I add a space between <span> and <input>, the <input> will come to a next line in chrome

Tags: css, flexbox

Everything is in this codesandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/static-31poq

Different browsers behave differently too.

Here is the screenshots

[chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZsiS.png)

[firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCYOh.png)

I know how to fix this. What I concern is what causes this.

```css
 .wrapper {
    display: flex;
    width: 80px;
  }
  .number {
    width: 70px;
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
      <div class="container">
      <!-- There is no space. Thus the input is in the same line. -->
        <span class="plus">+</span><input class="number" value="1"></input>
      </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
      <!-- There is a space. Thus the input comes to the next line.-->
        <span class="plus">+</span> <input class="number" value="1"></input>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can u explain clearly.

Comment: What is the stranger behavior ? is that the margin which is under <hr> ?

Comment: u teeling of plus icon changes aross browser????

Comment: Sorry, I have added some info to explain clearly.

Answer (score 1):

There is space between  and . Remove the space and it will display in one line. thanks

Comment: Thank you. But I just wonder what's causing this. Why a space (or some other text) can affect this?

Comment: I have noticed it happens with `inline` elements only. but not every time.

Comment: Yes, it happens randomly in different browsers and devices.

Comment: if this answer helped you then please mark it as answered. thanks

Comment: The space was added intentionally. It might be other strings. I just want to figure out how an inline text causes the difference of layout.

Answer (score 0):

Your `.wapper` width causes the problem try to increase the `.wapper` width. This problem happens due to different browser css presets. Different browsers have different default css presets therefore default rendering will be vary. To address this problem you can use css normalize style sheet or rest style sheet. However normalize style sheet and reset style sheet has different behaviors.

1. Normalize style sheet: https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/
2. Reset style sheet: https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

```css
.wrapper {
    width: 110px;
    display: flex;
}

.number {
  width: 70px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- There is no space. Thus the input is in the same line. -->
    <span class="plus">+</span><input class="number" value="1"></input>
  </div>
</div>
<hr/>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
  <!-- There is a space. Thus the input comes to the next line.-->
  <span class="plus">+</span> <input class="number" value="1"></input>
</div>
```

Chrome:
[image]

Firefox:
[image]

Comment: But in firefox the "input" will all come to the next line.

Comment: For me same result, what is your Firefox version ?

Comment: I added two image links in the origin post. You can click to see.

Comment: Just increase width ex: 110px. worked for me on Mac OS Firefox.

Comment: Thank u. And I know how to fix. I just wonder what's causing this.

Comment: Hope you will find answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22700119/css-appears-different-on-windows-than-mac, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4027755/css-difference-between-firefox-mac-firefox-windows